# Why does the preview image for my FFC look sharper than the actual captured image?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, front-camera

I feel this has been a problem on my Sprint Galaxy S3. The preview looks very crisp but when I actually take picture it becomes faded and bit blurry.

I know it's not motion from the tapping the button because it does not do it remains clear if I take a screenshot of the preview which is more shaky than just pressing the screen.

I took a picture and a screenshot of the picture to show what I am talking about:

[image: Screenshot of the preview] [image: Captured image]
<sup>Preview / Captured image (click images for larger variants)</sup>

In the preview you can clearly see the texture of my shirt and the freckles on my face while on the captured image it is just a solid blur.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any image filters/effects/night mode enabled? Try disabling them all?

Comment: Yes, I have all filters turned off. I have the "image quality" setting set to "super fine" and have tried both an auto white balance and fixed ones.