# Is there an app to use PNG for the FFC?

Tags: applications, front-camera

This is semi-related to a [previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/62912/53017) and I have a new theory I want to test. I am looking for a camera app that will store it's images in PNG format (what screenshots are stored in) instead of the lossy jpeg.

[Camera FV-5](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flavionet.android.camera.pro) is the only app I could find that mentions PNG support, but it does not support the FFC.

Answer (score 1):

JPEG with 100% compression quality is not lossless but maybe the picture quality will be good enough for you, here are two apps I know which has the ability to set the compression quality to 100%:

- [Snap Camera HDR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marginz.snap) (JPEG Quality: Best = 100% according to the [developers website](http://www.marginz.co.nz/#settings)), [trial here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marginz.snaptrial)
- [Camera MX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magix.camera_mx)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of JPEG to PNG, there are apps out there for conversion (based off of a quick search), one of them being: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.valsior.resizer
Also, if you have a Samsung device, I found this little tidbit that caused someone to save all their images as PNGs:http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-note-2/669470-camera-saves-images-default-png-format.html . Even then, they only save as this format after passing through Samsung's proprietary Photo Editor app on the person's Note II.

In terms of pure shooting in PNG, though, Camera FV-5 appears to be the only choice. :/ Hope this helped, and if anyone finds another app that can perform this function, I'd be interested in checking it out as well!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really get what I'm hoping for. Converting will just get me a perfect copy of the image that has already been distorted by compression.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that, but as far as I can see FV-5 appears to be the only way to shoot in the lossless PNG format on Android. Perhaps there is a way around this if your device is rooted? I'm not sure, that might take some digging in in the XDA-Dev forums. I'm looking forward to other suggestions from other users, though, as taking PNG images is something I'm looking into as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own using this [Cam API tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html).

Comment: I was thinking of going this route. It is just a lot of work for something that I am not sure will achieve my end goal. But others might have a use too so maybe I'll give it a shot if I get motivated.